# Is there a faster way to check if all objects in a python list are int instances (or some other class) than iterating over the list?

Tags: python

I'd like to verify that all objects contained in a given list are instances of `int` (or some other class, or set of classes).

For example, I can do this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in my_list:
  if not isinstance(i, int):
    raise Exception('Found a non-int!')
```

Is there a faster way than iterating over the list?  Do I need to extend the list class to contain a set of each added class or something?

Comment: I should have learned by now that it's worth doing timings. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) with [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) like this

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# return true
print(all(isinstance(i, int) for i in a))

b = [1, 2, 3, 4.5]

# return false
print(all(isinstance(i, int) for i in b))

#for list of instances
c = ['hello', 2, 3, 4]

#return true
print(all(isinstance(i, (int, str)) for i in c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me try again. My initial answer was concise but, alas, WRONG. On the same sort of theme it occurred to me to substitute a construction involving `lambda`. Correct result. Perhaps this would achieve the required results faster?

```
>>> my_list = [0,2,3,4]
>>> all(map(lambda x: type(x)==int, my_list))
True
```

Accordingly I timed the two approaches:

```
s = '''\
my_list = [0, 2, 3, 4]
for i in my_list:
    if not isinstance(i, int):
        raise Exception('Found a non-int!')'''

print (timeit.timeit(s))

s = '''\
my_list = [0,2,3,4]
all(map(lambda x: type(x)==int, my_list))'''

print (timeit.timeit(s))
```

with the following output:

```
0.6864084666728032
1.3789049683458745
```

Not only is the approach based on `map` not faster it takes twice as long. Undaunted (or pig headed if you like) I thought that there might be some sort of setup time that explains the performance of 'my' approach. So I tried a much bigger list.

```
s = '''\
my_list = list(range(2000))
for i in my_list:
    if not isinstance(i, int):
        raise Exception('Found a non-int!')'''

print (timeit.timeit(s))

s = '''\
my_list = list(range(2000))
all(map(lambda x: type(x)==int, my_list))'''

print (timeit.timeit(s))
```

with the following results:

```
305.03338925738615
478.1060787659975
```

Once again, the approach using `map` and `lambda` is much slower.

---

(I'm going to try to forget that I wrote this.)

Concisely:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4]
>>> all(map(int, my_list))
True
```

In Python, a list can contain items of any type.

```
>>> a_list = [1, 'b', 5, 7]
```